# How to load json into php with multiple json pages?

Tags: php, json, parsing

I try to get a json file into php. For now it works, except the latest (newest) data. The json feed contains only 10 items per page. But i want to get all data (pages) into php.

For example the url of the json feed (with the first 10 items) is: http://www.website.com/json/123456/?page=1

The url of the json feed (with the second 10 items) is: http://www.website.com/json/123456/?page=2

I tried to change the json url wihtout a parameter, but the file displays still 10 items. I know maybe a counter can fix the problem, but i do not have any idea how to fix this.

```
<?php
$json_url = get_field('review_json_url', 'option'); // path to my JSON file
$data = file_get_contents($json_url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
$reviews = json_decode($data); // decode the JSON feed  
?>          

<?php 

$sorted_reviews = array();
foreach ($reviews->beoordelingen as $review) {
    $sorted_reviews[] = array(
        'name'         => $review->klant_naam,
        'title'        => $review->title,
        'content'      => $review->tekst,
        'id'           => $review->CustorateID,
        'date'         => new DateTime($review->date_created),
    );
}

$count=0;
foreach (array_reverse($sorted_reviews) as $review) if ($count < 10) {
?>

<div class="review" id="<?php echo$review['id']; ?>">
    <h3 class="name"><?php echo $review['name']; ?></h3>
    <h5 class="location"><?php echo $review['date']->format('d-m-Y'); ?></h5>
    <h4 class="subtitle">"<?php echo $review['title']; ?>"</h4>
    <div class="content">
        <p><?php echo $review['content']; ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php $count++; } ?>
```

Comment: This is probably something you should not do on every single page load to begin with, but rather _cache_ the results somewhere on your end.

Comment: all data at one page is not a very good idea. Also if this URL exist at your end only then you can change the code in such a way that if page=all comes then send the whole records in json. If it's coming from another resources then you can't do anything

Comment: @04FS I placed the json into local files and created a new question. Just see my new question: [How to import multiple json pages into mysql database with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55968117/how-to-import-multiple-json-pages-into-mysql-database-with-php)